# Using d3js sort an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, sorting, d3.js

I have an array where each element in the array (representing a Supreme Court Chief Justice) contains an array of data points (the Chief Justice's name, number of disputes and year).

For each element in the top-level array, I need to sort the lower-level array in ascending order by year.

I attempted to sort year by ascending order using the following:

```
  nested_data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.values.sort(d3.ascending(d.values.year));
  });
```

But it did not sort the lower-level array in ascending order by year.

Here is the `console.log` of my nested data to show its structure.

```
Array[5]
  0:Object
    key:"Vinson"
    values:Array[7]
      0:Object
        chief:"Vinson"
        disputes:142
        year:Tue Jan 01 1946 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)
      1:Object
      2:Object
      3:Object
      4:Object
      5:Object
      6:Object
  1:Object
    key:"Warren"
    values:Array[16]
  2:Object
    key:"Burger"
    values:Array[17]
  3:Object
    key:"Rehnquist"
    values:Array[19]
  4:Object
    key:"Roberts"
    values:Array[11]
```

How can I sort the lower-level array in ascending order by year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the function:

```
nested_data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.values.sort(function(a, b) {
        return d3.ascending(+a.year, +b.year)
    });
});
```

Your original function had two problems:

1. Since you're sorting the `values` arrays, you don't need to repeat `values` in the `compareFunction`
2. When specified, `compareFunction` uses two parameters, normally named `a` and `b`. You have to put `d3.ascending` inside `compareFunction`. Have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Here is a demo with a bogus data:

```js
var data = [{
        key: "foo",
        values: [{
            chief: "Bob",
            year: 1982
        }, {
            chief: "Tom",
            year: 1977
        }, {
            chief: "Carla",
            year: 2010
        }, {
            chief: "Ana",
            year: 1999
        }]
    }, {
        key: "bar",
        values: [{
            chief: "Bill",
            year: 2009
        }, {
            chief: "Ted",
            year: 2014
        }]
    }, {
        key: "baz",
        values: [{
            chief: "Fred",
            year: 1998
        }, {
            chief: "Su",
            year: 1992
        }, {
            chief: "Charlie",
            year: 1999
        }, {
            chief: "Alice",
            year: 1979
        }]
    }, ];

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.values.sort(function(a, b) {
            return d3.ascending(+a.year, +b.year)
        });
    });

    console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```